# ImportError: No module named PyQt5 - OSX Mavericks

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, pyqt5

I'm trying to get PyQt5 running on OSX.  I downloaded and installed the Qt5 binaries.  Then, I downloaded the latest SIP source, compiled and installed it.  Finally, I downloaded the latest version of PyQt, compiled, and installed it.

```
python configure.py --qmake /Users/jsmaupin/Qt/5.1.1/clang_64/bin/qmake --sip /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/sip
```

I'm trying to get this to run on the default Python 2.7 installation.  It looks like the files were installed into the correct location (as far as I can tell) at /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/share/sip/PyQt5/

However, whenever I try to import anything from PyQt5 python reports that it cannot find PyQt5

The code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore
```

The result:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore
    ImportError: No module named PyQt5
```

I'm a Python newbie, so help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I hammered at this until I finally found a solution.  It seems like this might be a bug in the PyQt library installation or somewhere else.  I created a $PYTHONPATH environment variable to point to the newly installed PyQt .py files that hold references to the all of the Qt bindings.

```
export set PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

After that, everything worked like magic.  This includes PyCharm after going to Settings->Project Interpreter->Python Interpreters->Paths (tab), and clicking the "Reload list of paths" button with the blue circular arrows on the bottom.

Comment: I had this problem in PyCharm, it turns out the python interpreter being used was the one from my /usr/bin/python folder rather than the python version PyQt4 (in my case) was installed against, so watch out for it if you're still having problems

Answer (score 2):

An option is to download Anaconda. It automatically come with PyQt5. I found this to be the most simple way to obtain it. https://www.continuum.io/downloads

If you decide to use PyQt5 this way, you will have to use the IDE on Anaconda. I personally enjoy using Spyder (comes with Anaconda) as my IDE.

Comment: good answer
i read different topics and tried different ways to install pyqt but they did not work.
now it’s working with anaconda from https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/

Answer (score 2):

On macos I find I have to do both:

- Install PyQt5 from `$ brew install PyQt5`
- Ideally in a virtualenv run `$(pygui) pip install PyQt5`

in order for the module to be imported