# PyQt5 without QtGui and QtWidgets

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to build pyqt5 for my virtualenv but there is no QtWidgets package or module or whatever it should be. And I can't import QtGui.
This is how I try to build it:

```
python configure.py --qmake=/opt/Qt/5.2.0/gcc_64/bin/qmake
make
make install
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "there is no QtWidgets". Can you post the error message you're getting?

Comment: I get no error messages when i build PyQt. But there are just no modules called QtGui or QtWidgets in my PyQt package. So I cannot import them.

Comment: I had a problem like this. Check out my solution to see if it helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20179761/importerror-no-module-named-pyqt5-osx-mavericks/20192708#20192708

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### PyQt5 install using the python3-sip standard package

I faced the same problem yesterday. I solved it on Ubunutu 13.10 by removing the python3-sip package to which the PyQt5 installation seemed to refer to.

```
sudo apt-get remove python3-sip
```

and cleanup :

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

then install again sip 4.15.5 & PyQt5 in fresh environments (make clean) or restore the source directories.

**Note** : Some PyQt5 libraries (graphic based) lake for me after the installation. I had to install the libgl1-mesa-dev package before re-installing.

Hope that could help you.

Answer (score 2):

I found myself in the same situation with fresh Ubuntu install. I could import QCore, but not QWidgets or QGui (or several others).

Look at the output of configure.py, there should be a line:

```
These PyQt5 modules will be built: QtCore, QtGui, QtHelp, QtMultimedia, QtMultimediaWidgets, QtNetwork, QtOpenGL, QtPrintSupport, QtQml, QtQuick, QtSql, QtSvg, QtTest, QtWebKit, QtWebKitWidgets, QtWidgets, QtXml, QtXmlPatterns, QtDesigner, QtDBus, _QOpenGLFunctions_2_0, QtSensors, QtSerialPort, QtX11Extras, QtBluetooth, QtPositioning, QtQuickWidgets, QtWebSockets, Enginio, QtWebChannel, QtWebEngineWidgets
```

If this list is considerably shorter, missing QtGui etc, your installation may be missing OpenGL.
In my case...

```
sudo apt-get install freeglut3-dev
```

...installed enough graphics-related stuff so that the configure decided that it can try to build all modules. It is confusing, as the configure.py doesn't give an error (unless you use --verbose -flag), it just omits the modules it can't make. If it is not OpenGL, use --verbose with configure.py to find what is causing problems.

Comment: This worked for me on a newly installed Ubuntu 14.04.