# PyQt no module named

Tags: python, windows, pyqt

I try to use PyQt 5.5 with Python 3.5. I installed Python 3.5 (C:\Python3) and intalled PyQt 5.5 (C:\Python3\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5). Then I type

```
import PyQt5.QWidgets
```

and have the following error

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: no module named PyQt5.QWidgets
```

My OS is Windows 8 x32

It's not helped:

[ImportError: No module named PytQt5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20672918/importerror-no-module-named-pytqt5)

[ImportError: No module named PyQt5 - OSX Mavericks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20179761/importerror-no-module-named-pyqt5-osx-mavericks)

[PyQt5 and QtGui module not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17388082/pyqt5-and-qtgui-module-not-found)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED:** 
problem is gone when I installed Python 3.4 instead of Python 3.5

Answer (score 0):

You can also try recompiling your PyQt5.5 sources with Python 3.5 manually.
[Walktrough here](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/installation.html)